# Rails: efficient way of finding/replacing words in a large collection of records using a hash filter

Tags: ruby-2.0

Just wondering what the best way to approach this would be,

I have a large american to british english filter with about 2000 items

```
filter = {"authorized"=>"authorised"........}
```

and a large collection of about 4000 records

```
posts = Post.all
```

what would be the most efficient way to do a search and replace across a couple of properties (say `post.title` and `post.description`) for each record while maintaining original casing(ie. replace all characters after the first one only)?

edit: updated hash count

Answer (score 1):

I would think about using [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) and the hash syntax:

```
string.gsub(Regexp.union(filter.keys), filter)
```

To iterate over all posts use [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) to improve memory usage:

```
FILTER = { "authorized" => "authorised", ... }
FILTER_REGEXP = Regexp.new(Regexp.union(FILTER.keys), Regexp::IGNORECASE)

def translate(string)
  string.gsub(FILTER_REGEXP, FILTER)
end

Post.find_each do |post|
  post.update(
    title:       translate(post.title),
    description: translate(post.description)
  )
end
```

To support the original casing, I would add both versions to the hash (upcase and lowercase), that makes the whole regexp bigger, but makes the code easier to read and you avoid the extra logic to handle different cases. To generate a hash with both versions from you current hash, just use:

```
filter = Hash[*filter.map { |k, v| [[k,v], [k.capitalize,v.capitalize]] }.flatten]
```